# How to accessible Ansible machines with different password if first fails?

Tags: windows, ansible

I have some set of windows machines, which we are connecting through credentials in the inventory file.

For all the machines the username/password is the same.
But, for some machines, the password got changed.

So, we have one username and two passwords.
If the first one doesn't work then we try with the second password.

It is workgroup machines, not a domain.

Is there any way, we can frame in Ansible to retry with the second password if the first fails?

Answer (score 0):

Run a play with the old credentials to change credentials to expected value. Maybe set a local password with an Ansible module directly, maybe install something that will help manage the hosts.  Run some other play against the entire inventory to verify, and review any failed hosts.

Ansible's fail-fast approach means that incorrect credentials will immediately drop the host from the play as unreachable. Coming up with a scheme where you can change credentials is good security. And more productive than trying to hack in multiple credentials via [Ansible error tricks](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_error_handling.html#resetting-unreachable-hosts) like `meta: clear_host_errors` followed by setting some variable when a previous task  `is unreachable`.